# How to run Doxygen Makefile?

Tags: c#, makefile, latex, doxygen

I have created a .NET C# project that I have commented using blocks similar to `///<summary>A summary...</summary>` that I would like to document using Doxygen. I have set up Doxygen and it runs generating a some 100 .tex-files and a Makefile.

As I have understood, the Makefile is the key to generating the documentation as a PDF, however I do not get it to work.

I'm using a Mac to do the LaTeX and Doxygen bit by writing `make -f Makefile` in the Terminal when I am in the Doxygen LaTeX output directory.

```
all: refman.pdf

pdf: refman.pdf

refman.pdf: clean refman.tex
            pdflatex refman
        makeindex refman.idx
        pdflatex refman
        latex_count=5 ; \
        while egrep -s 'Rerun (LaTeX|to get cross-references right)' refman.log && [ $$latex_count -gt 0 ] ;\
            do \
              echo "Rerunning latex...." ;\
              pdflatex refman ;\
              latex_count=`expr $$latex_count - 1` ;\
            done


    clean:
        rm -f *.ps *.dvi *.aux *.toc *.idx *.ind *.ilg *.log *.out *.brf *.blg *.bbl refman.pdf
```

When running, i get the following message:

```
MacBook-Pro-13:latex sehlstrom$ make
rm -f *.ps *.dvi *.aux *.toc *.idx *.ind *.ilg *.log *.out *.brf *.blg *.bbl refman.pdf
make: *** No rule to make target `refman.tex', needed by `refman.pdf'.  Stop.
```

How can I get the Makefil thing work?

Comment: Did you run doxygen first?  Is LaTeX output enabled in Doxyfile?  Is there a `refman.tex` created?

Comment: @BenVoigt Yes, I have run Doxygen and it gave me about 100 .tex-files in the destination folder. Doxygen also created the Makefile as shown in the question. A file `refman.tex` is not created however - do I have to create that file? If that is the case, is there a specific way that document should be written to make the Makefile compatible?

Comment: I think that's supposed to be generated by Doxygen.  Did the `doxygen` command finish without errors?

Comment: @BenVoigt It finishes without errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`refman.tex` is supposed to be created by Doxygen.  I just tested with my installed version, doxygen 1.7.2, and it created a `refman.tex`.

Make sure you aren't setting any option that says this is a component of a larger project that shouldn't have its own index.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to check! I reset all settings and gave it ago again and now it produces the refman.tex file. However, when running make-f Makefile, the output is 4 pages with out any content =/

Comment: @sehlstrom: And you do have content in the HTML format?  There are a few settings such as `EXTRACT_PRIVATE_MEMBERS` or `EXTRACT_UNDOCUMENTED` that can cause almost all content to disappear, but they should affect both LaTeX and HTML equally.

Comment: The HTML output is fine, everything is there. Been testing around a bit and finally I get an error message saying what's wrong. For all .tex-files to be included in the refman.tex, I get something like this `LaTeX Warning: Reference `class_f_e_1_1solid2d_1_1_f_eplani4' on page 5 undefined on input line 10.` Corresponding line in refman.tex looks like this `\input{class_f_e_1_1solid2d_1_1_f_eplani4}`.

Comment: The script never got to an end. Just had to hit enter a few times to skip through all the warnings. Once that was done, I had 43 pages of documentation. Thanks for all your help @ben!

Comment: @sehlstrom: Ahh yes, tex warnings are fun.  Anyway, you can press `q`,`enter` to put it into silent mode and blaze past the remaining warnings.